# 2 Problems on Palindrome of Five Letters: A Letter appears more than twice and no letter does so.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A sequence of letters of the form $abcba$, where the expression is unchanged upon reversing order, is an example of a palindrome (of five letters).

(a) if a letter may appear more than twice, how many palindromes of five letters are there? of six letters

(b) Repeat part (a) under the condition that no letter appears more than twice

Comment: So, what are yourr thoughts on the questions? How far can you get? what do you know about permutations? Why are you interested in this particular problem?

Comment: for part (a) :
I use this way,
There are four possibilities form of the palindrome, they are
aaaaa ; baaab; ababa; aabaa; 
the possibilities of the first form is 26, 
the possibilities of the second form is 26 x 25 
the possibilities of the third form is also 26 x 25
the possibilities of the fourth form is 26 x 25

so, the number of palindromes of five letters with a letter may appear more than twice is 26 + (3 x 36 x 25)

is this correct?

Comment: I think you've left out abcba.

Comment: hhmm..., so I should add (26 x 25 x 24) ? 
and it will be 6 + (3 x 36 x 25) + (26 x 25 x 24) 
right?

Comment: Looks good, except that 36 looks like a typo.

Comment: re your first comment: usually one would define a as the first letter, so your baaab would be abbba, but your approach comes to the same thing.  You would just say the first three can be anything, so $26^3$, then the last two are defined.  Your approach should work if you are careful.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ahh..., I mean 26 + (3 x 26 x 25) + (26 x 25 x 24) :)

Comment: @RossMillikan yes.., I have to be careful using this approach since I have to consider cases..., 
so.., I just need to consider the first three letters and defined the rest two letters to make the words become palindrome, right?

Comment: so.., part (a), If it consist of six letters.., it will be same as the five-letters palindrome, $26^3$ palindrome of six letters correct?

Comment: That is correct.  The first three letters of six define the whole word.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  for a) the first half (round up-why?) determines the rest.  For b) this is a new restriction on the first half.  What about the middle letter?

Comment: what do you mean by round-up? 
I've tried to solve half of the part (a). 
I write it on the comment above.., is it correct?

Comment: @chihiroasleaf:  I meant if you have a word of five letters, it takes three to determine the rest.  If you have a word of six, it still takes three.  Gerry Myerson's comment is on point.

Comment: @chihiroasleaf:  for b, if a letter appears twice in the determining part (the first three) it will appear three or four times in the complete word, so you need the first three letters distinct.